# Using AMSlideMenu, re-enabling swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need help using the `AMSlideMenu` from https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu

In a project I'm creating I needed to disable the `AMSlideMenu` swiping so I could use the `UISwipeGestureRecognize` to perform another action.

The main swiping has been disabled `[self disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu];` and the menu is accessible by pressing the `menuBtn`, but I would like to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` which `AMSlideMenu` seems to be disabling.

Any ideas on how I could regain the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for my project?

Thank you!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu];

     UIButton *menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [menuBtn addTarget:self
           action:@selector(menuButtonTapped:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:menuBtn];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(swipeRecognized:) ];
     [leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(swipeRecognized:) ];
     [rightSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];
}

- (void)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.mainSlideMenu openLeftMenu];
}

-(void) swipeRecognized:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    int pageNum; 
    switch (swipe.direction)
    {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:{
            pageNum++;
            break;
        }
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:{
            pageNum--;
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share/add the swipeRecognized: method you've written?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question with it. For now I am only changing the pageNum up and down while I'm trying to make it work, but once it works I would like to use it to navigate through different segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change gesture in Table view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu];

     UIButton *menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [menuBtn addTarget:self
           action:@selector(menuButtonTapped:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:menuBtn];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(swipeRecognized:) ];
     [leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
     [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(swipeRecognized:) ];
     [rightSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
     [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];
}

- (void)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.mainSlideMenu openLeftMenu];
}

-(void) swipeRecognized:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    int pageNum; 
    switch (swipe.direction)
    {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:{
            pageNum++;
            break;
        }
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:{
            pageNum--;
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And now Just only Add an delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop left/right pan gesture from left menu controller class.

And then put your swipe gesture for specific view controller.

Follow steps below to stop swipe gesture for left menu:

1) Go to `AMSlideMenuMainViewController.m` class, in that select `- (void)setup` method.

2) Comment following lines from this method will stop swipe gesture.

```
    self.panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [self.panGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];


    [self.currentActiveNVC.view addGestureRecognizer:self.panGesture];
```

3) After commenting these lines create a swipe gesture in your ViewController and handle your custom logic.